ionic datetime component converting date back and assign
I am using ionic datetime component. While ability to set the value works fine but when i try to set the selected value back i am struggling.
the code looks like below:
 <ion-datetime-button datetime="datetime" style="border: 1px solid #AEB1B5"></ion-datetime-button>
      <ion-modal [keepContentsMounted]="true">
        <ng-template>
          <ion-datetime id="datetime" presentation="date" (ionChange)="dateChanged($event)" (value)="calcStartDate()"></ion-datetime>
        </ng-template>
      </ion-modal>

the .ts file is
 dateChanged(e:any) {
    console.log('ionChange fired with date value: ' + e.detail.value);
    this.income["Date"] = (new Date(e.detail.value)).getTime()
  }

  calcStartDate(){
    console.log("Start date is:", new Date(this.income.Date))
    return new Date(this.income.Date)
  }

The value stored is for field "Date" is of type number to play nice with firebase data store.
With above code i am still getting today's date rather the saved value.

Are you having any warings or error in console? Also, are you getting a correct value in this.income.Date?

You should NOT be using ionChange and value like that together. thats why when you set it, it runs ionChange then it runs the other method you placed : calcStartDate(). You should not be running a method within the value. You do all the changes needed in the ionChange.

@StackoverBlows do u have the correct example to do this?

You need square brackets for variables in angular:
[value]="calcStartDate()">
